# Convert filter into regex

Tags: java, regex

I've been looking out if there is any java converter library to translate simple filters for example  `*something*` into a regular expression like `(.*)something(.*)`. 
The use case would be to allow end users to create regular expressions without knowing the whole regex syntax. Does anyone know if there is any work done or has anyone an idea how to accomplish it.

Comment: explain more what you want? this is for a file or project.

Comment: for a project, it's a web app in which users may introduce a simple filter to filter out the data which can be almost anything, from url to simple human written text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KISS. Keep It Simple, Stupid.

Assuming you want `*` for zero or more characters, and `?` for a single character (same as file name globbing on most OSes), you could just use something like this (typed in browser, so not tested, but you get the idea...)

```
String filterToRegexExpression(String filter) {
    String regexExpression = filter
        .replace('?', '.')
        .replace("*", "(.*)");
    return "^" + regexExpression + "$"; // anchor or not at either end, as desired
}
```

Then just create a regex instance and use this conversion function to convert the user-supplied filter string into a regular expression.

The above doesn't handle other regex-special characters very nicely, but I think you can do that by simply escaping anything non-alphanumeric. I'm leaving that as an exercise for the reader, though.

I doubt there are ready-made libraries for this, since that would require defining a universally acceptable but somehow easier regular expression syntax - while the application's needs (and expectations on the user's knowledge) tends to vary quite a bit. At that point, you can almost as well just ask them to input a regular expression, for which there are plenty of examples available.

Comment: Yes that was the first approximation i did but as the user may enter any string i'd need also to ensure they're not entering any regex special character such as `{|+$^[()]}` and it would be great we could translate the expression both ways, regex into filter and filter into regex, so users are able to edit it.

Comment: See the second-to-last paragraph about regex-special characters (which is a fairly limited set and should be easy to test for). As for translating back and forth, why bother? Unless this is performance critical (in which case you definitely should not use regular expressions!), just store the user-provided filter string and convert it to a regular expression when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this approach to replace all character.

you need:

```
jakarta-regexp-1.5.jar
```

standerd way to implement using build.properties or web.xml

```
<replaceregexp file="${src}/build.properties"
                         match="OldProperty=*"
                         replace="NewProperty=(.*)"
                         byline="true"/>
```

replaces occurrences of the property name "OldProperty" with "NewProperty" in a properties file, preserving the existing value, in the file ${src}/build.properties

see http://www.jajakarta.org/ant/ant-1.6.1/docs/en/manual/OptionalTasks/replaceregexp.html for more